# Cannot import a json in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, openshift

I am using RockMongo in Openshift to import a json file in MongoDB database. I exported directly the json from another MongoDB and I haven't changed anything. Here is a part of the json:

```
{ "_id" : "10352",
 "author" : "8988607", 
"country" : "...",
 "views" : 1716,
 "title" : "...", 
"comments" : 1, 
"likes" : 28, 
"text" : "...", 
"date" : { "$date" : 1278070740000 }, 
"approved" : "8480596" }
```

And I have this error message:

```
exception: field names cannot start with $ [$date] at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:147
```

As I said, I exported the json directly from another MongoDB. How can I solve this problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up against this problem and my dba replaced the dollar sign with \uFF04 and that did the trick for us.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB uses its [Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). Rockmongo likely uses a standard JSON parser, thus the mismatches.

Can you use the provided [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) application? You will need to use v2.4.0 or greater to include all the extended types see: [SERVER-5675](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5675)