# Populate mongo collection for java tests

Tags: javascript, java, json, mongodb

I'm trying to populate an in memory mongo database for the tests.
I'm using `mongo-java-driver 2.13.3` using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/ I can run javascript code to my in memory database.

Using `mongoexport` with `--out output.json` flag I'm getting all the documents that I need in a [extended](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) json format.

Then I wrap these json documents with `db.myCollection.insert()` and try to insert into my databse using `db.eval`.

But since these documents have extended json format I'm getting the following error:

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:12345" , "errmsg" : "exception: field names cannot start with $ [$oid] at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:147" , "code" : 16722 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this or if I should use other approach to achieve that.

This is an example of what I'm trying to insert:

```
db.keywords.insert({"_id":{"$oid":"53cd13a4e4b0d5282d586abf"},"name":"musculación","categoryId":{"$oid":"54180551d98ed9a5334110b3"},"photo":null,"created":{"$date":"2014-07-21T13:20:36.056Z"},"updated":{"$date":"2016-09-27T16:17:36.692Z"}});
```

Comment: Can you post a sample document you are inserting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on the syntax but your error is mongo complaining about trying to insert a '$' reserved character field.

I tried the insert with your document and got the same error:

```
> db.keywords.insert({
...     "_id": {
...         "$oid": "53cd13a4e4b0d5282d586abf"
...     },
...     "name": "musculación",
...     "categoryId": {
...         "$oid": "54180551d98ed9a5334110b3"
...     },
...     "photo": null,
...     "created": {
...         "$date": "2014-07-21T13:20:36.056Z"
...     },
...     "updated": {
...         "$date":"2016-09-27T16:17:36.692Z"
...     }
... })
2016-11-17T10:13:18.263-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: field names cannot start with $ [$oid] :
DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:185:1
DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:189:13
Bulk/this.insert@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:646:9
DBCollection.prototype.insert@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:271:13
@(shell):1:1
```

If you revise the syntax it will obviously work - I don't know if this is valid with the Java driver but you could try it:

```
db.keywords.insert({
    "_id": ObjectId("53cd13a4e4b0d5282d586abf"),
    "name": "musculación",
    "categoryId": ObjectId("54180551d98ed9a5334110b3"),
    "photo": null,
    "created": ISODate("2014-07-21T13:20:36.056Z"),
    "updated": ISODate("2016-09-27T16:17:36.692Z")
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733243/cannot-import-a-json-in-mongodb but I'm wondering if there is another way to achieve that without changing manually the $id and $date. Something which can convert from extended json format to mongo shell mode